# How to scrape dynamic data using scrapy library

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

In the below link, remitmoney foreign   rate is coming in dynamic.Iam not able to scrape data.I need to know how to do it with dynamic data.
import scrapy

```
class MyRemitSpyder(scrapy.Spider):
name = "toscrape-remit"
start_urls = ["https://www.remitmoney.com/send-money-UK-to-India"]

def parse(self,response):
        for reviews in response.xpath("//div[@class='exchangeratebox']"):
            yield{
            'text':reviews.xpath(".//div[@class='change-lable exchange-send-wrap']//label/text()").extract_first(),
            'currency':reviews.xpath(".//div[@class='change-lable money-fixed']//label/text()").extract_first(),
            }
```

Comment: 2017-09-06 09:54:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.remitmoney.com/send-money-UK-to-India>
{'text': None, 'currency': None}

Comment: Iam getting above term in output